# EXIT a paragraph from a called paragraph

Tags: cobol

i am trying to exit a paragraph from a called paragraph
This is my code:

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   display "PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT"
   display "PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1"
   PERFORM NOM_PROC1 THRU E--NOM_PROC1
   display "PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1"
   display "PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN"
       GOBACK.

   NOM_PROC1.
       PERFORM LABEL1 THRU E--LABEL1
       CONTINUE.
   E--NOM_PROC1.
       EXIT.

   LABEL1 SECTION.
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > 4
          display "PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL1 CALL N°" I
          PERFORM LABEL2 THRU E--LABEL2
          PERFORM LABEL3 THRU E--LABEL3
       END-PERFORM
       CONTINUE.
   E--LABEL1.
       EXIT.

   LABEL2.
         display "PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL2"
         display "PGM LEAV9POW: I WILL LEAVE LABEL1"
         EXIT SECTION
         CONTINUE.
   E--LABEL2.
       EXIT.

   LABEL3.
         display "PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL3"
         CONTINUE.
   E--LABEL3.
       EXIT.
```

I have as a result:

```
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL1 CALL N°01
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL2
PGM LEAV9POW: I WILL LEAVE LABEL1
```

I think i should have:

```
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL1 CALL N°01
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL2
PGM LEAV9POW: I WILL LEAVE LABEL1
PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN
```

Thanks in advance for yours helps and advices.

This is the code that worked for me:

```
   PROC1.
       PERFORM LABEL1 THRU E--LABEL1
       PERFORM LABEL4 THRU E--LABEL4
       CONTINUE.
   E--PROC1.
       EXIT.

   LABEL1 SECTION.
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > 2
          display "PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL1 CALL N " I
          PERFORM LABEL2 THRU E--LABEL2
          PERFORM LABEL3 THRU E--LABEL3
       END-PERFORM
       CONTINUE.
   E--LABEL1 SECTION.
       EXIT SECTION.

   LABEL2.
         display "PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL2"
         display "PGM LEAV9POW: I WILL LEAVE LABEL1"
         IF J = 1 THEN
            EXIT SECTION
         END-IF
         CONTINUE.
   E--LABEL2.
       EXIT.

   LABEL3.
       display "PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL3"
       CONTINUE.
   E--LABEL3.
       EXIT.

   LABEL4.
       display "PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL4"
       CONTINUE.
   E--LABEL4.
       EXIT.
```

Comment: The output should be :

PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL1 CALL N 01
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL2
PGM LEAV9POW: I WILL LEAVE LABEL1
PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN

But i have:
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL1 CALL N 01
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL2
PGM LEAV9POW: I WILL LEAVE LABEL1

Comment: Are you using GnuCOBOL or OpenCOBOL (older version of the same thing)? If not, what compiler are you using? There is a compiler bug. Taking your program with GnuCOBOL it produces that output and that is incorrect. The output you are expecting would be the correct output. I think you have chosen the entirely wrong way to do what you want, but that doesn't stop it being a compiler bug.

Comment: I am using cobolit, it's derived from opencobol

Comment: Thanks. I'll report the bug to GnuCOBOL (which will include OpenCOBOL). Can you report the bug to COBOLIT? I really think the GO TO would be better, but can't be certain without knowing what it is you are trying to emulate from PL/I, or what you are allowed/have time to restructure.

Comment: I think that my code was wrong.
indeed, i didn't place paragraphs between two section.
When i did that, it worked correctly.

This the change:
       PROC1.
           PERFORM LABEL1 THRU E--LABEL1
           CONTINUE.
       E--PROC1.
           EXIT.

       LABEL1 SECTION.
           CONTINUE.       
       my_paragraphs......
       E--LABEL1 SECTION.
           EXIT.

Comment: Can you use the edit link under your question to include also the new code which works for you? Your existing code is valid code where the EXIT SECTION doesn't work as expected. You may have located a workaround which gives a hint as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. That is really tortuous stuff. Even if it works in CobolIT, the next person looking at it is going to take far too long to understand it, and in two weeks time you will have no clue how it "works". It still doesn't work with GnuCOBOL, but that's different issue. There's no good way to say how bad that code is. I can detail what is happening in an answer if you like, but it is a nightmare, even in that short piece of code. Changing that code in the future would require real care. I strongly suggest you abandon this, and return to you other question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix, from the top level original listing.  Drop the THRU when performing the LABEL1 SECTION

```
   NOM_PROC1.
   PERFORM LABEL1 THRU E--LABEL1
```

to

```
   NOM_PROC1.
   PERFORM LABEL1
```

and compile the code with -cb_conf=perform-osvs:yes

We'll look into some of the deeper issues, but the code is bumping into an old System/370 compatibility issue (the default) in regards to section ends not being detected when jumping into the last paragraph, versus so-called OSVS mode where the section jumps have special testing regarding the last paragraph.  (That is somewhat of an oversimplification of what is going on here).

THRU with SECTION is something that we'll need to look into.  Either a warning, or a code flow correction in GnuCOBOL to make this work as expected.

```
prompt$ cobc -xjd secex2.cob -cb_conf=perform-osvs:yes
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT
PGM LEAV9POW: DEBUT PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL1 CALL N°01
PGM LEAV9POW: I AM LABEL2
PGM LEAV9POW: I WILL LEAVE LABEL1
PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN PROCEDURE NOM_PROC1
PGM LEAV9POW:   FIN
```

That's with the THRU E--LABEL1 phrase commented out from the original listing and GnuCOBOL 2.0.  GnuCOBOL 1.1 should work the same way given a .conf setting with `perfrom-osvs: yes` once the section THRU is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, I haven't written any COBOL in more than 30 years...

`EXIT SECTION` does precisely what it sounds like it does; it exits the entire section completely. In your case, this returns you to `NOM_PROC1` which in turn returns you to the main procedure.  You could try:

```
EXIT PARAGRAPH
```

Comment: Since `EXIT SECTION` and `EXIT PARAGRAPH` are from the 2002 Standard, I guess you read up anyway :-) `EXIT PARAGRAPH` won't do what the OP wants, which is to break out back to the original PERFORM. Yoiks, a working EXIT SECTION, in this case, should behave like that.

Comment: I did go and look it up since it looked unfamiliar. Reading his expected output it seemed like he expected it to return to the next line in the previous paragraph within the same section, not back to the original perform. Did I read that wrongly?

Comment: Yes, it is part of a series of questions which seem to relate to converting PL/I programs to COBOL. The operation of breaking out of a nested loop in PL/I is different from the "EXIT PERFORM" and someone, unwisely in my opinion, suggested using "EXIT SECTION" with the code in a SECTION. The intention is to break out of a PERFORM of a paragraph *within* a SECTION to immediately go back to where the SECTION was performed. So much bad practice...

Comment: Then there is no way to simulate the leave statement to an equivalent in cobol ?

Comment: @MohamedELKHALIFI as I answered previously, if you need to keep the structure of the PL/I for your COBOL program, then you should use `GO TO label`. It's not exactly great, but better than using `EXIT SECTION` which is nothing but a "secret GO TO" which doesn't specify a named label. If you are allowed to restructure the code, then you have to show what type of thing, with a real example, not a made-up one, so that you can get advice.